# Convert a Datetime to a String upon a condition (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a Datetime object which I take from an XML file (closingDate).

I want to dynamically display all closingDates to the user. However, not all objects in the XML file necessarily contain a dateobject.

How can I do this (pseudocode):

```
DateTime closingDate = DateTime.Parse(xmlFile.selectSingleNode("Closing_Date")).toString();
```

and then later, I am writing out an HTML file with:

```
    String fileListHTML += "<li><a href='#'>The file name gets put here</a> (Closed:
"+closingDate+")</li>";
```

Now, as long as there is a datetime, there is no issue. However, if there is no datetime object (ie: null), I get an error.

Can I somehow do an if statement to say (again, pseudo):

```
if (closingDate =="")
{
   closingDate = "To be determined";
}
```

I am, of course, getting an error about casting a datetime to string.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So, first line of code here: you're taking a string (xml)... parsing it to a DateTime... calling toString() so you have a string again (just formatted different)... and then assigning that string to a DateTime variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of turning `DateTime`s to `string`s until it is necessary.

You could use a nullable DateTime.  Use null to denote it's not set or parsable.   Alternatively scratch the nullable approach and use a sentinel such as `DateTime.MinValue` instead.

This is untested but should get the point across:

```
DateTime? closingDate;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myClosingDateString))
{
    closingDate = DateTime.Parse(myClosingDateString);
}

// do whatever else you need

// when it comes time to appending ...

if (!closingDate.HasValue) // or check if it's `DateTime.MinValue`
{
    fileListHtml += "No closing date";
}
else
{
    fileListHtml += closingDate.Value.ToString();
}
```

I'd caution you to be careful about converting `DateTime` to strings without considerations to time zones and internationalization (for example, `DateTime.Parse()` can interpret dates very differently depending on regional settings and/or the culture you pass in).

For simplicity, if you can control the format of the string, I'd suggest using UTC and the ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.TryParse instead, here's a sample code showing how it works:

```
DateTime res;
if ( DateTime.TryParse(str,out res))
{
   // Res contain the parsed date and you can do whatever you want with
}
else
{
  // str is not a valid date
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ch92fbc1.aspx